# How to set YUV 255:255:255 and 0:0:0 using fade filter

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to [fade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) in|out YUV 255:255:255 and 0:0:0 color, but check RGB color using [datascope](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#datascope) filter setting YUV 255:255:255 and 0:0:0, then sets color option at fade filter dose not display YUV 255:255:255 and 0:0:0.

Set YUV 255:255:255

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color,format=yuvj444p,lutyuv=255:255:255 -vframes 1 255.png
```

Check RGB Hex using datascope filter

```
ffmpeg -i 255.png -vf datascope rgb.png
```

Set color option 0xff79ff

```
ffprobe -f lavfi -i "color,format=yuvj444p,fade=out:nb_frames=1:c=0xff79ff,signalstats,trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=2" -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.signalstats.YAVG,lavfi.signalstats.UAVG,lavfi.signalstats.VAVG
```

output

```
TAG:lavfi.signalstats.YAVG=167
TAG:lavfi.signalstats.UAVG=167
TAG:lavfi.signalstats.VAVG=177
```

Same way YUV 0:0:0, but dose not fade to YUV 0:0:0.

Answer (score 1):

The default pixel format for `color` is yuv420p, which is limited range. The LUT filter will clip any set values to `(minval,maxval)` which is `(16,235)` for limited/mpeg range. To force full range, convert to a full range YUV format. e.g.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color,format=yuvj444p,lutyuv=255:255:255 -vframes 1 255.png
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Fix commands, but dose not YUV 255:255:255.

Comment: How are you checking for colors? Run the command `ffplay -f lavfi -i color,format=yuvj444p,lutyuv=255:255:255,datascope`. It shows the average color of blocks in Hex. I get FF FF FF.

Comment: Check RGB color Hex by datascope filter one line.
`ffplay -f lavfi -i color,format=yuvj444p,lutyuv=255:255:255,format=rgb24,datascope`
FF FF FF displays YUV 255:255:255. `ffplay -f lavfi -i color,format=yuvj444p,lutyuv=255:255:255,datascope`

Comment: I don't follow you. If you get FF FF FF with your 2nd command, then it works. Right?

Comment: Fade filter dose not support YUV Hex. RGB Hex 0xff79ff dose not mean YUV 255:255:255. `ffprobe -f lavfi -i "color=c=0xff79ff,format=yuvj444p,trim=end_frame=1,signalstats" -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.signalstats.YAVG,lavfi.signalstats.UAVG,lavfi.signalstats.VAVG`

Comment: Ok, turns out that this is more complicated than it looked. Since RGB and YUV are both being stored as 8-bit values, the conversion has to clamp the solution values if they go out of bounds. And since YUV stores a [larger range](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/503873#FIG6-5) of colors than RGB, albeit with lower precision, a YUV->RGB->YUV roundtrip may not result in identity, even ignoring rounding. Takeway: use the format solution I provided, and don't think about the corresponding RGB values.

Comment: Fade filter dose not support high bit depth [https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_fade.c#L101](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/vf_fade.c#L101) , so I give up setting YUV 255:255:255 and 0:0:0 using fade filter. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: Don't follow. If fade did support higher depths, 255:255:255 would not be its max value. If all you want to do is interpolate from 255 to 0, fade will work. Just don't do a RGB conversion.